# LinearLayout and FrameLayout multiple errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

So I am currently making this app and this is the activity_maps.xml file that I am using/coding:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nearby Schools"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The errors which are showing are that whenever I hover my mouse above linearlayout it shows: layout_height attribute should be defined, layout_width attribute should be defined, Element LinearLayout doesn't have required attribute layout_height, Element LinearLayout doesn't have required attribute layout_width, Wrong orientation?No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent". Then these are the errors when I hover above FrameLayout: layout_height attribute should be defined, layout_width attribute should be defined. These are the errors when I hover above the button tag: layout_height attribute should be defined, layout_width attribute should be defined. These are the errors when I hover above abdroid:id="@+id/btnwhatever", android:text="whatever", android:visibility="visible" tags they all say: Unexpected namespace prefix "android" found for tag Button.
When I change the layout of the app to this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp">

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:text="Nearby Schools"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

However when I do that layout which shows no errors and then I open the map it says on the logcat:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute
Please help, Thank you.
P.S. I just took out the tools:context="" tag in the fragment for posting

Comment: Dear Mike, I have put the /> at the end of the fragment code and it is showing in the log cat when I run the app: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute and the app just crashes saying: Unfortunately, Map  has stopped working. Please Help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same error as yours.

And I found out that in FrameLayout, make sure it's **http** instead of **https**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

instead of

```
xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.
```

Just remove the 's'. And it works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

As Mike said and also remove repeated xmlns `xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from FrameLayout tag. Here is the code that I have tested:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nearby Schools"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 1) Removing the duplicate attribute is not related to the problem OP is facing. It's just a suggestion so better post it as a comment!
2) The code you posted doesn't represent what you are asking OP to do
3) `<fragment>` tag can be closed with  `/>` rather than `> </fragment>` as Mike said in the comment.

Comment: Dear Ruben, I have put the /> at the end of the fragment code and it is showing in the log cat when I run the app: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #0: You must supply a layout_width attribute and the app just crashes saying: Unfortunately, Map has stopped working. Please Help, Thanks!

Comment: @SandipSoni only after I posted my tested code I see mike has found an error `>` instead of `/>`. Also not that `> </fragment>` is not correct. So at the time of post my answer was bugfree, it's always better to test, isn't it? Also at first two lines I asked the OP what to do!

Comment: @TEPneil if you copy paste my code, it's still the same? have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: @ruben, I have copy and pasted your code and guess what? It worked! now the problem is that the buttons are not showing up, however it is showing up on the design of the app and the frame layout and fragment are very small, however the app shows the map largely and the current location is able to be shown. Please help,Thanks man

Comment: @TEPneil This is because you need to change the `height` of all the elements. How much `height` each element is going to take. You can also use the attribute `layout_weight` to tell how much space each should take.